# meaning of "to seem"

Tags: meaning

> to seem = to give the effect of being;

Does this effect cover the person itself or It is not necessary?
For example is the following sentense correct?

> I seem to know more about him than anyone else, but I know that I know
> nothing about him

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "cover" and "the person itself"? There's two people in that sentence. All verbs indicate something about their subject, in this case "I".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While that is technically OK, a better verb to use there would be "appear" or "pretend".

Comment: I don't understand why you might think "seem" isn't as good as "appear" or "pretend" in this context, but "pretend" carries a completely different meaning anyway.

Comment: I think the point of the question is that the speaker may "give the effect of being" knowledgeable (etc.) to someone else despite privately knowing otherwise. Hence "appear" or "pretend" would convey it clearly.

Comment: It's true that if a person says of themselves that they ***seem*** to have some attribute, it's at least *feasible* the speaker is deliberately giving that impression. But that would be a very unlikely usage. Almost always, when someone says *I seem to be X* they mean *It appears **to me** that I'm X*. Only if they specifically meant *I deliberately make myself appear to be X **to others*** would someone say *I pretend to be X*.